# Compute $\int_0^{a_1} \int_v^{a_2} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}u) \exp(-bv ) I_0(c \sqrt{ v \, u}) \,du \,dv$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to compute the following integral:
$$\int_0^{a_1} \int_v^{a_2} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}u) \exp(-bv ) I_0(c \sqrt{ v \, u}) \,du \,dv,$$
where $a_1$, $a_2$, $b$ and $c$ are positive constants, and $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Note that $u$ and $v$ are $\ge 0$.

Any idea on how to do the calculation ?

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-au-bv}I_0\Big(c\sqrt{uv}\Big)~du~dv ~=~ \frac4{4ab-c^2}$$

Comment: @Lucian Could you please tell me if this result can help me to compute the integral ? if so, how ?

Comment: @din: Such definite integrals are not known to possess a closed form over random intervals.